# Using '=' operator to make two arrays equal in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, equality

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Fun(int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
    arr1=arr2;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[i]<<" "<<arr2[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr1[5];
    int arr2[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        arr1[i]=i+1;
        arr2[i]=i;
    }
    
    Fun(arr1,arr2);
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[i]<<" "<<arr2[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, why is arr1=arr2 in the Fun function, but on returning back from the function, arr1 has its initial values only?

Comment: Your misunderstanding is that neither `arr1` or `arr2` are arrays. They are both pointers and `arr1 = arr2` only makes the `arr1` pointer point at the same array that the `arr2` pointer is pointing at. But that change is local to the function.

Comment: Try writing `arr1 = arr2` in main and you will see that `=` does not work for arrays, and it only compiles in `Fun` because neither `arr1` or `arr2` are arrays there.

Comment: `std::array<int, 5>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function arguments, `int arr1[]` has the same meaning as `int *arr1`.

```
arr1=arr2;
```

is an assignment of pointers and now `arr1` and `arr2` point at (the head of) the same array, so the same array is printed in `Fun()`.

On the other hand, the assigment affect only the pointer and not the arrays pointed at, so it will not affect `main()` function.

To copy the contents of arrays, you can use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy

void Fun(int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
    std::copy(arr2, arr2 + 5, arr1);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr1[i]<<" "<<arr2[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: or `template<size_t N> void Fun(int (&arr1)[N], const int (&arr2)[N]) { std::copy_n(arr2, N, arr1); }` to be safer.

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

you are simply assigning the address of the array `arr2` to `arr1`. So while this makes it *appear* as if the arrays are copied inside the function, this doesn't actually copy the contents of the arrays.

To do that you can use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) like this:

```
std::copy(arr2, arr2 + 5, arr1);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ofhvb3).